# __builtin_clz() is negative

Tags: c++, built-in

I have some code like this:

```
int foo(unsigned long long x) {
    unsigned int x1 = (unsigned int)(x >> 32);
    unsigned int x2 = (unsigned int)(x);

    if (x == 0) {
        cout << x1 << " " << __builtin_clz(x1) << endl;
        cout << x2 << " " << __biultin_clz(x2) << endl;
    }
}
```

The output on `x = 0` is:

```
0 587581823
0 -32
```

And the most strange thing is that `__builtin_clz(x1)` which is here equal to `587581823` always different random number (some times less than 0) and `__builtin_clz(x2)` is always `-32`

Comment: Isn't `__builtin_clz` undefined when its argument is zero? Which it is guaranteed to be in your case.

Comment: @amaurea may be its undefined, I dont really know. I searched a bit and in all places I saw it was 32. If it's undefined, then the first large random number is ok, but why the second number is always -32 then?

Comment: @Dima: "Undefined" is really a bad category. "Yellow" is also a valid outcome. Don't try to reason about the details.

Comment: This function is not standard C++.  This is a compiler intrinsic.  What compiler, version, and CPU architecture are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look on the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) for `__builtin_ctz` we have:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_ctz (unsigned int x)`
>
> Returns the number of trailing 0-bits in x, starting at the least significant bit position. If x is 0, the result is **undefined**. [emphasis mine]

Undefined is undefined. The completely arbitrary numbers you see as the result are well within the confines of "undefined".

Answer (score 3):

You can't use __builtin_clz with a value of 0

The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) says:

> — Built-in Function: int __builtin_clz (unsigned int x) Returns the
>   number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most significant bit
>   position. If x is 0, the result is undefined